# Player based betting odds VS analysis based odds

Tags: odds, risk

there are two kinds of betting sites

1. Player based odds sites (thunderpick.com , csgopositive.com , ...)
2. analysis based odds sited (1xbet , bwin , and almost all of the huge betting sites)

when you calculate your odds base on players you never lose, example:

I put 1 dollar on **A** team and you put 1 dollar on **B** team, now if either of these teams wins site will get some profit (odds are never 100% site will get between 2 - 5 % of outcome)

but when you calculate your odds base on analysis odds will never change and if you put 1 million dollars on a team odds will stay the same for both teams but here is the problem for me. I will explain it by an example:

the site predetermined the odds and A team will give you 1.29 * your money and the B team will give you 2.69 * your money.

we assume I and my friend are the only ones who play in this site.

now if I bet 10$ on the B team and my friend 10$ on the A team if the B team win the site will lose money.

why big sites don't go with the safe road how much more possibly they can profit from analysis based odds?